# Fine Uploader error with internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-10, fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader 3.7.0 in a project with Chrome and Firefox and it works fine, but with Internet Explorer 10 the files are uploaded correctly but the user always get the "Upload failed" error message, even with the demo tests:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     var errorHandler = function(event, id, fileName, reason) {
            qq.log("id: " + id + ", fileName: " + fileName + ", reason: " + reason);
        };

    var myUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
        element: $('#basicUploadButton')[0],
        multiple: false,
        callbacks: {
            onError: errorHandler
        },
        request: {
            endpoint: '/fineupload/receiver'
        }
    });
});
</script>
<div class="fineUploader">
    <span>Please upload your files for automated process.</span>
    <div id="basicUploadButton" class="upload-btn"></div>
</div>
<br />
<div><a href="#" onclick="window.close()">Close Window</a></div>
```

I debugged the servlet and I see that I am sending this:

```
writer.print("{\"success\": true, \"uuid\": \"" + requestParser.getUuid() + "\", \"originalFileName\": \"" + requestParser.getFilename() + "\"}");
```

so I think that the JSON I am supposed to get is correct.

Any ideas why can this be failing with IE10? I also tried with the compatibility modes and didn't work.

Updated: Console log:

```
[FineUploader 3.7.0] Error when attempting to parse xhr response text (SyntaxError: Invalid character) 
 id: blog.jpg, fileName: Upload failure reason unknown, reason: [object XMLHttpRequest]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure you are using IE10?  If so, are you using it in compatibility mode or quirks mode?  Also, please include the console log messages in your question.

Comment: Yes, I am using IE10 in the default mode (Browser mode: IE 10, Document mode: Standards). I also tried compatibility modes. No one worked. Please let me know if I should use something different.

Comment: Please include all log messages written to the console in IE10 when this happens.

Comment: Included in the body of the message. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing: please add a "debug" option, set it to true, reproduce the issue again, and then paste the contents of your console once more.  This time, the actual contents of the response will be logged to the console.  This should give me more insight.

Comment: I think I got it. The requestParser.getFilename() returns with IE something like c:\\folder\\blog.jpg in the JSON response. I added code to remove the c:\\folder\\ part and it seems it works. I will do some tests and confirm.

Comment: Please list the exact contents of the response, either via the method I suggested or by copy and pasting the response body from the network tab for the associated response in IE10 dev tools.

Comment: @user2066291, what language are you writing your server in? There must be some sort of JSON serialization library that you can utilize. It looks like there is some error going on with string escaping when using the `writer.print()` method as you are. Also, use the IE debug tools to take a peek at what the JSON response is, and pass it into [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) to ensure that it is properly formatted.

Comment: The wrong response is {"error": "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\data\uploads\fd9b5240-5661-4f07-a216-7a76b2250b00_C:\folder\blog.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"}. That is because I am creating the file uid with a uuid and the file name. The file name in IE is c:\folder\blog.jpg but in Firefox and Chrome is only blog.jpg, so it works. Modifying how I get the file name, it works.

Comment: So, it looks like this had nothing to do with IE10 at all.  You were simply not returning valid JSON in your response.

Comment: There really were two problems, the creation of the JSON and the way IE manages the file names. I will explain it in the thread answer (I cant put it yet), but yes, using a valid JSON creation fine uploader worked fine but the variable still was wrong (in FF and Chrome it was ok).

Comment: If there is a bug in Fine Uploader, please file a bug request.  I haven't come across any issues in IE10 though myself.

Comment: I won't say that it is a bug, the serialization solved the message issue but not my problem :). I think you will see it as soon as I am able to post the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was due to the JSON response I was creating in Java.

Looking at the Network tab in IE10 developer tools (thanks Ray for the advice) I get:

```
{"error": "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\data\uploads\fd9b5240-5661-4f07-a216-7a76b2250b00_C:\folder\blog.jpg (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)"}
```

I was using

```
writer.print("{\"success\": true, \"uuid\": \"" + requestParser.getUuid() + "\", \"originalFileName\": \"" + requestParser.getFilename() + "\"}");
```

Instead of that

```
JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject();
json.put("success", true);
json.put("uuid", requestParser.getUuid());
json.put("originalFileName", requestParser.getFilename());
writer.print(json.toString());
```

works fine with every browser.

Anyway, I needed to avoid the file name that IE10 manages (C:\folder\blog.jpg) so I had to use

```
json.put("originalFileName", getCorrectFileName(requestParser.getFilename()));
```

with getCorrectFilename(String s) removing the "C:\folder\" part.

Answer (score 0):

The question of "my file is sent to the server but Fine Uploader reports a failure" is a common one.  As the docs state, you MUST return valid JSON in the response to Fine Uploader's upload POST requests.  Based on your comments, you were not returning valid JSON.  To verify that you are returning valid JSON, you can use a tool such as [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com).   You can examine the response payload via your browser's developer tools, or set the `debug` option to `true` in your Fine Uploader options.

As @mfeltner stated, you should be using a JSON serialization tool server-side when constructing your response.

Comment: Yes, I already have the answer with @mfeltner and your help, thanks :). As I am new to Stackoverflow, I can not put the full explanation in the next 6 hours. I will update the thread with it. Regards